# How to edit header.tpl in CMS Made Simple

Tags: cmsmadesimple

I am new in CMS Made Simple and I need to edit header.tpl file. I found the file location here tmp/templates/header.tpl but when I do any change in this file, it does not affect anything at frontend.

I need the help to edit header.tpl file.

Comment: "I need to edit header.tpl file" you almost certainly don't need to do this. What are you trying to achieve? There will be a better way.

Comment: because I want to add some HTML part in the header section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit your website header: Login to admin area. Go to Layout -> Templates. Click the template in use (often the one ticked Default). Edit the template as required. Click Submit. You should never edit files in the tmp area.